# Dripping dryer vent clean/dry help

Tags: pipe, dryer, vent, venting

The issue is every summer when we are running AC when it is 85 degrees outside, the dryer vent pipe starts to drip in 1-3 spots.

I have an 18.5 ft dryer vent that goes from my first floor down a foot into the basement, runs along the duct work (gets cooled down) then does a 45 deg turn before going up and out of my house. So 3 90 deg turns (including the one directly behind the dryer) one 45 deg turn.

I read you have 35 ft, minus 5 ft for each 90 deg turn, so 20, then minus 2.5 ft for 45 deg turns, so EXACTLY 18.5 ft for code.

I run the vent brush through from both ends and it comes out with really wet and packed lint. I open it up in the middle, run the brush both ways, wet vac it out both ways, and then let it dry a bit before taping it back up.

Any way to avoid this? Should I clean every spring before we turn on the AC? Any way to dry the wet pipe out? Run cool air through the dryer?

Thanks!

Comment: Pictures? Is this solid metal, accordion metal or accordion plastic?

Comment: Have you considered insulating your vent piping?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Solid metal. Taped with shiny thin duct tape. I am thinking of insulating to prevent the condensation. It is still dripping as of this morning after I cleaned it all out and ran cool air (air dry cycle) through a few times.